# take the name/path of the current route

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, navbar

i have this navbar:

```
 <nav class="menu">
   <a routerLink="textArea" class="menu-item">text-area</a>
   <a routerLink="dropdown" class="menu-item">dropdown</a>
   <a routerLink="autosuggest" class="menu-item">autosuggest</a>
   <a routerLink="manageCookies" class="menu-item">manage-cookies</a>
   <a routerLink="progressBar" class="menu-item">progress-bar</a>
 </nav>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and the routes declared in the app.routing:

```
 const routes: Routes = [
   {
     path: 'textArea',
     component: TextAreaComponent,
   },
   {
     path: 'dropdown',
     component: DropdownComponent,
   },
   {
    path: 'autosuggest',
    component: AutosuggestComponent,
   },
   {
     path: 'manageCookies',
     component: ManageCookiesComponent,
   },
   {
     path: 'progressBar',
     component: ProgressBarComponent,
   },
 ];
```

I would like to apply a class to the navbar if the route where I click is, for example, progressBar ... what do I do?
To be clear, I would do something like this:

```
 <nav class="menu" [class.myClass]="currentRoute === 'progressBar'">
   .......
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should use the router module, you can pass any number of classes in the routerLinkActive. You can check [here](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive) for more details.

```
 <nav class="menu">
   <a routerLink="textArea" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active', 'class 1']" class="menu-item">text-area</a>
   <a routerLink="dropdown" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']" class="menu-item">dropdown</a>
   <a routerLink="autosuggest" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']" class="menu-item">autosuggest</a>
   <a routerLink="manageCookies" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']" class="menu-item">manage-cookies</a>
   <a routerLink="progressBar" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']" class="menu-item">progress-bar</a>
 </nav>
```

If you want to do it dynamically, you can do something like this:

```
 <nav class="menu" [ngClass]="urlBased">
   .......
 </nav>
```

In your Ts file add a method to populate `urlBased` based on route activated:

```
// Sample code to follow
 constructor(private router: Router) {
          router.events.subscribe((url:any) => { 
          console.log(url)); // url will be the path or use this.router.url
          //this.urlBased = this.router.url;
          this.urlBased = url;
           if(this.urlBased && this.urlBased.length > 0){
            this.urlBased = this.urlBased.slice(1);
            if (this.urlBased == 'progressBar') this.urlBased = progressBar;
          }
   }
  }
```

Comment: But I want to put the class at <nav>, no at <a>

Comment: route.url tells me it doesn't exist!

Comment: Updated the answer, check the url path and match with it. You can also create a swtich if you have multiple dynamic classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `routerLinkActive` property directly together with `routerLink`.

```
<a routerLink="textArea" [routerLinkActive]="['myClass']">text-area</a>
<a routerLink="dropdown" [routerLinkActive]="['myClass']">dropdown</a>
```

Comment: But I want to put the class at <nav>, no at <a>